# How to write into an .xlsx file with 2 pre-defined worksheets using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, office-interop

I'm working on a project which fills details into custom (pre-defined) `.xlsx` template files, which then opens the Excel app for further user input. Note that the file opened is in memory, so that the user won't have to go to the trouble of saving it to a local file first before it's actually opened.

So far I'm doing good on files with one worksheet using the basic code somewhere in the lines of:

```
excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Workbooks wbs = excelApp.Workbooks;
Workbook wb = wbs.Add(pathOfTemplate); //<-- I'm guessing the problem is this line?
Worksheet ws = wb.Sheets[1];

//Fill details
ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Sample data";

//Show app
excelApp.Visible = true;
```

Now that I encounter a multi-sheeted workbook, I tried to modify the code to have another `Worksheet` variable, inserted to the code above:

```
Worksheet ws2 = wb.Sheets[2];
ws2.Cells[1, 1] = "Sample data again";
```

What I get is two Excel instances opening, with no details being writted to any of the worksheets. I've tried the `Worksheet.Activate()` method but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did to open a blank xlsx file?

Comment: @reds What do you mean? If you're saying the opened `xlsx` was blank, no; it opened the pre-defined file without any of the details written in C# program.

Comment: what i mean is,, you are starting to a blank existing xlsx file. then fill out with a data from your project

Comment: @reds Nope, it's pre-defined with all the column headers and signatories for example, in it. What's left for the code to do is to fill in the body or details. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *don't* use interop. The `xlsx` format was created to allow applications, especially services and web sites, to generate and read Excel files without starting a new instance of Excel each time they need to create a sheet.

You can use a library like [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) to read a sheet as a template, modify it and save it using a new name :

```
var newFile = new FileInfo("pathToNewFile.xlsx");
var templateFile = new FileInfo("PathToTemplate.xlsx");

using(var pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile,templateFile))
{
    var ws=pck.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

    //Set a cell's text
    ws.Cells["A1"].Value ="whatever";
    ws.Cells[2,1].Value ="whatever2";

    //Fill cells from a collection
    var orders=new List<Order>();
   //Fill the list then ...
    ws.Cells["A10"].LoadFromCollection(orders);

    pck.Save();
 }
```